# Not able to see content in content finder in CQ5

Tags: aem

I have imported images and videos inside CQ5 repository. I am able to see all of them inside DAM(digital asset management) but when i am creating a page using already defined templates and components , I am not able to see them(images and videos) in the content finder menu.

Comment: Hi Abhijeet, are you seeing any errors when opening the page with the content-viewer? (/crx-quickstart/logs/error.log).  Are you seeing anything in any tab of the Content Finder?

Comment: I guess I had done few mistakes. I changed nt:folder to sling:orderedfolder, nt:file to dam:asset and then I added metadata node to jcr:content node for an image file. Now I can see image files both in DAM and content finder. but i am not able to see the content of the file. I found that in the error.log, for every persisted image , jcr:content/metadata] com.day.cq.dam.core.process.XMPWritebackProcess null. I guess this is because i need to supply xmp metadata details also. If i am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: Do you mean you can't see the image / the video won't stream, or you can't see the metadata. Can I suggest that if you're having issues and have heavily customised the DAM or CF structure, that you first try it out on another vanilla install, adding in your customisation one by one to see where the problem lies (generally good practice, even outside CQ). It will be hard to debug your problem without knowing how much you have changed the functionality I'm afraid.

Comment: I have created a program which imports images and other stuff inside cq5 repository which is working fine. Now i have to create components and templates using persisted images. Nodes i was using earlier were simple and plain provided by cq5(nt:folder for folder and nt:file for files) and storing them under directory /content/dam/{folders directory}/filename/jcr:content. With this, I was able to see images and their content in cq5 dam. when i created pages based on my components i could not find those images in the content finder and then made changes as stated in my last comment

Comment: Normally, when you add an asset to the DAM, its node gets a `jcr:primaryType` of `dam:Asset` and it's child `jcr:content` node of `dam:AssetContent`. You mentioned that the nodes themselves are now `dam:Assets`; have their children been updated also?

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you running?   I've seen this issue with CQ5.4 with the MSM feature pack.   A similar issue affects some browsers in CQ5.5 with update 1.
Otherwise, I'd check the error logs as mentioned in the comments.  Look for DAM workflow failures or similar such errors.

Answer (score 0):

When you open page with content finder see which call is loading images.

For example here in mentioned link assets are loaded from `/content/dam/assets` path.

[http://localhost:4502/bin/wcm/contentfinder/asset/view.json/content/dam/assets?_dc=1466163645234&query=&mimeType=image&*charset*=utf-8](http://localhost:4502/bin/wcm/contentfinder/asset/view.json/content/dam/assets?_dc=1466163645234&query=&mimeType=image&_charset_=utf-8)

[image]

**How to get this url**

1. Open page in chrome
2. Enable "Network" view
3. Click on refresh icon in content finder

[image]